# Autorefactor with intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ keeps refactoring my code;

```
public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

into something like this;

```
public void setOwner(Owner owner) {this.owner = owner;}
```

where is the feature responsible for that? I'd like to turn it off.

Comment: I don't think it is collapsing the setter to one line. It just displays it like that. Check the raw file on disk

Comment: Look at the left side of the line. You see a "+" there. Click it, and IntelliJ displays the original code. Note: cricket_007 is right, IntelliJ just **displays** it that way. The original source file does not have it stored like that.

Comment: If you want to disable this, go to File / Settings, Editor / General / Code Folding, then uncheck "One-line methods".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default IntelliJ is set to "fold" or "collapse" certain types of code for example, one-line methods.

If you want to change it, open Preference & go to Editor -> General -> Code Folding and un-select some or all the options.